# Compound MEL statement has problems

Tags: mule, mule-el

I need to read values from a configuration file and I keep running into issues with an embedded MEL statement; chased multiple dead ends and am out of ideas. I distilled it down to a fairly simple example using a session variable.

Thank you,
- Don

The below code fails with:
Message               : [Error: Missing left node]
[Near : {... message.payload.contains(#[sessionVars['valueToMatch']]) ....}]

```
    <set-session-variable variableName="valueToMatch" value="Now we are engaged in a great civil war" />        
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[message.payload.contains(#[sessionVars['valueToMatch']])]">
            <set-session-variable variableName="success" value="true" />        
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-session-variable variableName="success" value="false" />       
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
```

Whereas the following code works:

```
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[message.payload.contains('Now we are engaged in a great civil war')]">
            <set-session-variable variableName="success" value="true" />        
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-session-variable variableName="success" value="false" />       
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is that you are putting an expression delimited inside of an expression, try this:

```
"#[message.payload.contains(sessionVars['valueToMatch'])]"
```

instead of this

```
"#[message.payload.contains(#[sessionVars['valueToMatch']])]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `#[message.payload contains valueToMatch]` ... It will work perfectly and simple:-

```
<set-session-variable variableName="valueToMatch" value="Now we are engaged in a great civil war" />        
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[message.payload contains valueToMatch]">
            <set-session-variable variableName="success" value="true" />        
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-session-variable variableName="success" value="false" />       
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
```